# Чтение из InputStream с указанной позиции

Tags: java, apache, ftp

У меня есть класс, который с помощью Apache commons io FTP постоянно опрашивает указанный текстовый файл каждую секунду, лежащий на ftp сервере (запущенном на другой машине).

Этот файл много весит, по этому я сохраняю в переменную кол-во байт, которое я прочитал в последний раз и с этой позиции начинаю считывать файл в следующий раз (когда в файл добавили что-то).

Я использовал skipNbytes, но оказалось что он пропускает байты, за счёт вызова метода read(), в следствии чего, каждую секунду происходит передача целого огромного файла.

Вопрос в следующем, как полноценно пропустить определённое кол-во байт перед чтением (чтобы без вызова метода read()), чтобы прочитать файл условно говоря с середины?

```
private List<String> getFileRows(FTPClient ftpClient) {
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(FILE_NAME);
        inputStream.skipNBytes(lastByteRead);
        byte[] receivedBytes = inputStream.readAllBytes();
        inputStream.close();
        ftpClient.completePendingCommand();
        LinkedList<String> rows = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.stream(new String(receivedBytes).split("\r\n")).toList());
        lastByteRead += receivedBytes.length;
        lastRowRead = rows.getLast();
        return rows;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Failed to get FTP file rows");
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Не [оно](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10102821/3129992)?

Comment: @XelaNimed к сожалению нет, реализация skip в BufferedReader так же начинает выкачивать файл, при вызове skip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут дело не в `InputStream`, а в протоколе ftp.

Вам нужна команда [restart](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#restart-long-) из ftp клиента, который вы используете:

```
ftpClient.restart(lastByteRead);
InputStream inputStream = ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(FILE_NAME);
```

Нужно только, чтоб сервер ее поддреживал, т.к. не все сервера это умеют.

Если не поддреживает, то вариантов нет. `InputStream` сам по себе умеет пропускать только читая файл. Некоторые реализации, такие как, например, `ByteArrayInputStream` умеют пропускать, так там все данные доступны сразу и нет привязки с потокоориентированному протоколу.

Comment: Это именно то, что мне требовалось, спасибо огромное!